# Force MP4, BA, and <480p?

Tags: ffmpeg, yt-dlp

### *Jump to d.1 to see the work-around command I am using.*

### Why am I doing this?

It is SOMETIMES best to just do -f ba[ext=m4a] then change the extension to .mp4, my concern being that it will sometimes fail (or that it can be done more concisely)!

OTHER TIMES: I need the lowest quality file, must be video, that can still give a general idea of what's visually occurring (usually 144p or 360p).  I don't want to sacrifice audio quality if at all possible.  I always have to compress and re-format things: sometimes it takes an hour--I really want to cut steps down.

### My goal is:

- *Understand how yt-dlp and ffmpeg work better.*
- Download the **highest audio quality** and a **specific video quality**.
- Use the ***fewest commands possible*** to handle all potential inputs.
- **Get an mp4 output** (not webm, not raw audio), consistently; ideally, without use of ffmpeg, if possible; alternatively, to use a single command that includes the yt-dlp string and the ffmpeg string on one line (such as `yt-dlp -flags && ffmpeg -flags`).

### Known problems:

*Best guesses* **did not work**:

a.

1. `yt-dlp https://url.com/uri -f wv+ba* -o "./my/location/filename.mp4"` where wv means worst-audio and ba means best-audio and the ***the `*` should mean "somehow make best-audio the priority!"*** Sadly, I get mixed results: usually a worst-video file with no audio.
2. `yt-dlp https://url.com/uri -f wv+ba -o "./my/location/filename.mp4"`.  Give the wrong extension.

b.

1. `yt-dlp https://url.com/uri -f ba[ext=m4a] -o "./my/location/filename.m4a"` This gives me an m4a file and then I need to do a rename command `[ext=mp4]` is not an option.  This also does not give video, which is **NOT IDEAL**.

c.

1. `yt-dlp https://url.com/uri -f 134+ba -o "./my/location/filename.mp4" --merge-output-format mp4`, where `id 134` is 360p video.  This gives `ERROR: Postprocessing:   Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (copy)`, and there is no merged output file (only two tmp files with audio-only and video-only).
2. `yt-dlp https://url.com/uri -f 134+ba -o "./my/location/filename.mp4" --merge-output-format mkv && rename filename.mkv filename mp4`, where `id 134` is 360p video.  This gives a file that is an mp4 file, but it is seen by the system as an mkv file (and cannot be used for the desired purpose).

d.

1. `yt-dlp https://url.com/uri -f 134 -o "./my/location/filename.webm && yt-dlp https://url.com/uri -f ba -o "./my/location/filename.m4a" && ffmpeg -i .\relativePath\inputFilename.f251.webm -i .\relativePath\inputFilename.f248.webm -c:v mpeg4 -q:v 0 -q:a 0 -c:v copy .\relativePath\outputFilename.mp4"`.  Note: the audio/video can be input in any order, but **the -i flag should come first**.

### About workaround d.1:

If I use `-q:a 100`, the output file will be 10 times larger than the input files; so, I think I am not getting lossless audio....

Note: the audio/video can be input in any order, but **the -i flag should come first**.

Also, it is important to not use asterisks `bv*+ba` because that will prioritize the best video quality with combined audio, and you need separate files: you can guarantee separate files by excluding the asterisk.

Comment: Have you tried JDownloader yet? After your last similar question I'd assume you have...

Comment: `ba` selects a format that contains only audio. `ba*` selects a format that *may* contain a video stream. I'm not sure `wv+ba*` make sense (you can just try...)

Comment: @PierU
It doesn't work, wv+ba* gives me a lq video with no sound.  And wv+ba gives me an .mkv file.  So I think the best solution is to get worstvideo and bestaudio and then either convert or manually merge?

Comment: Check about the `--remux-video` and `--merge-output-format ` options

Comment: i tried --merge-output-format for example, and it turns out no sound.  --remux-video gives me a corrupt file.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is specifically not allowed (I found the info in a "codec" section of the yt-dlp manual).  The best way to go about this, as far as what I've found in-practice, is with the --merge-output-format option and **be careful of typos**.  Because this isn't possible, I continued working and wrote a bash script.  The bash script is just section d as a bash function, where the URL, downloaded filename, and output filename are the arguments; finally, I use rm downloadfilename to delete the file.  If nobody answers, I'll post the script on 11/11/2022.

Comment: With ffmpeg and a bash script you can do everything you want. But it does no longer meet your own initial requirement *"ideally, without use of ffmpeg, if possible; alternatively, to use a single command "*

Comment: @PierU Ultimately, only one bash command is used, but yt-dlp does not have the functionality to obtain the desired result.  It cannot remux or recode into h.264 format; so, there is no way to achieve the desired result.  I will often get v9 format, which is useless to me.  Thank you for your comment.